# Connecting to SQL db with ADODB

Tags: python, sql-server, adodb, adodbapi

I am trying to connect to a SQL database with ADODB connection. I am not getting an error with my code, however nothing is populating. Can anyone advise what I may be doing wrong? thanks!

Also I'm trying to use adodbapi as I am seeing a lot of samples using this package, however I am unable to install on terminal and python packages screen

```
`import win32com.client

def ado():
    conn = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
    DSN = ('Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; DATA SOURCE =' +myserver+';Initial Catalog='+mydatabase+';UID='+user+';pwd='+password)
    conn.Open(DSN)

    rs=win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Recordset')
    strsql = "SELECT * FROM DocumentInvoiceDetail"
    rs.open(strsql, conn)
    t = rs.GetRows()
    conn.close()
    return t`
```

I've also tried to use pyodbc method and getting stuck with an error "Data source name not found and no default driver specified

```
    import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Devart ODBC Driver for SQL Server};Server=myservername;Database=databasename;Port=port;User ID=user;Password=pw')
```

**EDIT**: I was able to resolve utilizing the code below, looks like changing the driver to *SQL Server* did the trick thanks!

```
import pyodbc
from pprint import pp
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=database;UID=user;PWD=pw')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Comment: Not sure if you have a particular need to use ADODB, but Microsoft endorses [pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver16) as its connectivity driver for python.

Comment: No particular need, however not sure if the particular SQL server I am trying to access needs ADODB. I've tried to use pyodc and having issues as well, will edit my post with what I tried

Comment: Glad to see you got it sorted! Please answer your own question with what you found so that anyone who comes across the same problem can easily see your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve utilizing the code below, looks like changing the driver to SQL Server did the trick thanks!

```
import pyodbc
from pprint import pp
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=server;DATABASE=database;UID=user;PWD=pw')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Comment: Note the "SQL Sever" ODBC driver that ships with windows is provided only for backwards compatibility and hasn't been enhanced for 20+ years. It would be better to use a [newer Microsoft ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16), which is a separate dowload and install.